# LiveData<Data> Observer not called on data changed in android studios java

Tags: java, android-studio

I had an observer for LiveData LD but the observer's onChange(Data pData) method was not being called when I made modified data like LD.getValue().modify().

I'm answering this cuz I was unable to find a solution to my specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

The observer's onChanged(data) is not called when the wrapped data is modified. It's called when the wrapped data is replaced with some other data. For example

```
LD.getValue().modify();
```

Won't work but

```
newData = LD.getValue();
newData.modify();
LD.setValue(newData);
```

will call the observer.
I think you can use postValue(newData) also. Haven't tried it cuz setValue worked.
Here is the guide from where I understood this
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#java